# SSL needed on redirect?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I inherited a weird situation from a client that I'm no expert at. This client has 3 domain names, the main one being, for example, domain-a.com. They also have domain-b.com and domain-c.com redirecting to domain-a.com. All domains live on the same server.

So the problem comes up because they had SSL certs on all 3 domains and the cert on domain-c.com expired and they need to get a new one. This had me thinking, do they even need certs on domain-b or domain-c if it just redirects? Also consider that the domain-c.com domain is the domain of their email, but as far as I know, the two don't affect each other.

TL;DR: Do you need SSL certs on redirects to a page with an SSL cert.

Comment: If a request ever comes in for `https://domain-b.com/anything` or `https://domain-c.com/anything`, then yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes.**

The redirection is an HTTP-level action which happens inside the SSL envelope.
The client needs to establish an SSL connection to the original host **before** it 'sees' the redirect, then after completing the redirect it must establish another SSL connection to the target host.
So you definitely need an SSL certificate on redirects to a page with one.

Comment: No. Since as you said after being redirected the TSL handshake has to be done again with domain-a, then there's no need for a SSL connection on domain-b. But if the user tries to access https://domain-b.com, then she'll get an error unless you have a cert installed on domain-b

Answer (score 2):

If you have requests via TLS to domain-b & domain-c than yes, you need TLS support on them.

There's also a security related aspect in this. Plain text communication to domain-b.com & domain-c.com means a plain text redirect to domain-a.com. Because it redirects to SSL only the communication to domain-a.com is secured. This leaves the redirect from domain-b & domain-c vulnerable to a MITM attack. An attacker can intercept the requests and redirect the client to a different site under their control.

This is not easy to prevent, unless you have something like [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security) (HSTS, [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797)) in place on all domains *and* the visitor visited the sites before *or* they're in preload list of their browser.

In any case, to make it more secure: Upgrade the client to TLS on their first request to any of the three domains, and redirect to https instead of http when going to domain-a from domain-b & domain-c. Use HSTS with preload and [HTTP Public Key Pinning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning) on all domains and you're good to go.